UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\ud83c' in position 0: surrogates not allowed
I am trying to parse "https://tre.tbe.taleo.net/tre01/ats/servlet/Rss?org=arobpers2&cws=42" but I am getting the error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\ud83c' in position 0: surrogates not allowed". I tried looking at other questions with UnicodeEncodeError but this one seems to be different since chardet outputs that the text is ASCII encoded.
import chardet                                                                                                                                                                                                                
import feedparser                                                                                                                                                                                                             
import requests  
url = "https://tre.tbe.taleo.net/tre01/ats/servlet/Rss?org=arobpers2&cws=42"
r = requests.get(url)
print(chardet.detect(r.text.encode())) # Outputs ASCII
feed = feedparser.parse(r.text) # Raises UnicodeEncodeError


I was able to solve the issue using html.unescape():
import feedparser     
import html                                                                                                                                                                                                        
import requests
 
url = "https://tre.tbe.taleo.net/tre01/ats/servlet/Rss?org=arobpers2&cws=42"
r = requests.get(url)
txt = html.unescape(r.text)
feed = feedparser.parse(txt)


The XML contains invalid values such as &#55356;&#57119;
They do not represent valid Unicode characters.
In this case, you could simply remove or replace them.
Perhaps substitute them with a question mark.
Something like this:
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

url = "https://tre.tbe.taleo.net/tre01/ats/servlet/Rss"
params = {
    "org": "arobpers2",
    "cws": 42
}

with requests.get(url, params=params) as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
    xml = re.sub(r"&#[0-9]{5};", "?", response.text)
    ET.fromstring(xml)

Update:
You could take this a step further and validate all such patterns as follows:
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

url = "https://tre.tbe.taleo.net/tre01/ats/servlet/Rss"
params = {
    "org": "arobpers2",
    "cws": 42
}

with requests.get(url, params=params) as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
    xml = response.text
    for p in set(re.findall(r"&#[0-9]+;", xml)):
        o = int(p[2:-1])
        if not chr(o).isprintable():
            xml = xml.replace(p, "?")

    ET.fromstring(xml)


The string r.text contains invalid values such as &#55356;&#57119;. They represent numeric html escapes of surrogate pairs. You could simply replace them with valid numeric html escapes (e.g. &#55356;&#57119; -> &#127775; for  in this case).
The code: (used a piece of hard-coded text instead of r=requests.get(url)):
import html
import re
r_text = 'sometext0 &#55356;&#57119; sometext1 &#55356;&#57119; sometext2' \
    '\n' 'sometext3 &#55356;&#57118; sometext4 &#55356;&#57117; sometext5' \
    '\n' 'nosurrogatepairs &#55291;&#63744; another &#55290;&#63749;'

print(f'\n{r_text}')
print(f'\n{html.unescape(r_text)}')

def surrogates_2_code(highsurr,lowsurr):
    if ( highsurr >= 0xD800 and highsurr < 0xDC00 and 
         lowsurr  >= 0xDC00 and lowsurr  < 0xE000):
        return 0x10000 + ( (highsurr - 0xD800) << 10) + (lowsurr - 0xDC00)
    else:
        return 0


def surr_repl(matchobj):
    m = re.findall(r'(\d{5})' ,matchobj.group(0), flags= re.ASCII)
    code_point = surrogates_2_code( int(m[0]), int(m[1]))
    if (code_point >= 0x10000):
        return f'&#{code_point};'


pattern = r'(&\#5[56]\d{3};&\#5[67]\d{3};)'

print( f'\n{re.sub( pattern, surr_repl, r_text, flags=re.ASCII )}')
print( f'\n{html.unescape(
    re.sub( pattern, surr_repl, r_text, flags=re.ASCII ))}')

Output: \SO\78568676.py
sometext0 &#55356;&#57119; sometext1 &#55356;&#57119; sometext2
sometext3 &#55356;&#57118; sometext4 &#55356;&#57117; sometext5
nosurrogatepairs &#55291;&#63744; another &#55290;&#63749;

sometext0 �� sometext1 �� sometext2
sometext3 �� sometext4 �� sometext5
nosurrogatepairs ퟻ豈 another ퟺ串

sometext0 &#127775; sometext1 &#127775; sometext2
sometext3 &#127774; sometext4 &#127773; sometext5
nosurrogatepairs &#55291;&#63744; another &#55290;&#63749;

sometext0  sometext1  sometext2
sometext3  sometext4  sometext5
nosurrogatepairs ퟻ豈 another ퟺ串

